# Must .vimrc be located in the home directory?

Tags: vim, terminal

I just moved my .vimrc, .vimrc~, ..vimrc.un~ files from my home directory into a folder called .vim. Now all of the preferences I made in .vimrc are not working when I edit a file in vim. I then moved my .vimrc file back into my home directory and all of a sudden my preferences are working again.

This leads me to wonder: does .vimrc need to be in the home directory? If so, why? And is there any way to change this?

I'm a total newbie with vim and so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See this question for options: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11879/how-can-put-vimrc-and-viminfo-into-vim-directory

Answer (score 5):

- Your `.vimrc`, with a period, *must* be in your `$HOME` directory:

  ```
    ~/.vimrc
  ```
- You can move it to your `~/.vim/` directory but you *must* drop the period:

  ```
    ~/.vim/vimrc
  ```

Trying random things is a losing strategy. Instead, consider reading the relevant documentation and doing things properly. From `:help vimrc`:

```
[...]

Places for your personal initializations:
    Unix          $HOME/.vimrc or $HOME/.vim/vimrc
    MS-Windows    $HOME/_vimrc, $HOME/vimfiles/vimrc
                  or $VIM/_vimrc
    Amiga         s:.vimrc, home:.vimrc, home:vimfiles:vimrc
                  or $VIM/.vimrc
    Haiku         $HOME/config/settings/vim/vimrc

The files are searched in the order specified above and only the first
one that is found is read.

RECOMMENDATION: Put all your Vim configuration stuff in the
$HOME/.vim/ directory ($HOME/vimfiles/ for MS-Windows). That makes it
easy to copy it to another system.

[...]
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to check where your Vim config files should be located:

```shell
$ vim --version | grep vimrc
```

You should see something like this:

```
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
```

So for user vimrc file, you could place it as `$HOME/.vimrc` or `~/.vim/vimrc`.